# Powershell to Set User Account Password to Never Expire

Tags: powershell

```
Set-ADUser -Identity <name> -PasswordNeverExpires $true
```

Set-ADUser : The term 'Set-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:1
+ Set-ADUser -Identity $Name -PasswordNeverExpires $true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-ADUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Sounds like the PowerShell activeDirectory module has not been imported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the ActiveDirectory module:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

To check if it exists:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

If you don't see the ActiveDirectory module, then it's because you did not install AD LDS Users and Computer Feature. Go to Manage - Add Roles & Features. Within Add Roles and Features Wizard, on Features tab, select Remote Server Administration Tools, select - Role Admininistration Tools - Select AD DS and DF LDS Tools.

ActiveDirectory module is present by default in windows server 2008 R2, install it in this way:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell
```